Pandas-Profiling conflicts with scikit-learn
When i try to install pandas profiling in my jupyter notebook then i encounter an error as
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the 
packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following 
dependency conflicts.
scikit-learn 1.5.1 requires joblib>=1.2.0, but you have joblib 1.1.1 which is 
incompatible.

Now again,when i try to upgrade the version of joblib,then i would encounter new error as
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the 
packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following 
dependency conflicts.
pandas-profiling 3.2.0 requires joblib~=1.1.0, but you have joblib 1.4.2 which is 
incompatible.

Again upgrading imbalanced-learn & scikit-learn would give me same incompatible error.
How can I resolve this error and properly install pandas-profiling?

If you require both scikit-learn and pandas-profiling in your environment then to resolve conflicts between 2 libraries you can install both of them with one statement that is:
pip install scikit-learn pandas-profiling

The statement above automatically takes those versions of both libraries where there is no conflict in dependencies. But remember to uninstall both libraries before running above command.
Or (I have tested) you can install pandas-profiling with 3.6.6 version with the below command:
pip install pandas-profiling==3.6.6

In this case you don't need to uninstall scikit-learn as above version of pandas-profiling also take joblib version of 1.4.2. So there will not be any conflict in this installation.

Try to install ydata-profiling (https://pypi.org/project/ydata-profiling/) since pandas-profiling is no more active and ydata-profiling is its evolution.
